# Joomla site access not allowed due to forgotten password

Tags: joomla

I have a site in Joomla built quite a long time ago, in the old version of Joomla. Now I have to make some changes to the Joomla site and I had lost my password and even on going to the area for lost password. I can't access the site. How can Iget out of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the access to your files through FTP, so the solution is very simple.

Acess the files and find the configuration.php file. There you will find the Host, username, password etc, of your Joomla database. Then go to the jos_users table, and try to use this tool to change your password : [Generate a new password for Joomla 1.0.x](http://www.teachmejoomla.net/joomla-mambo-tutorials-and-howtos/general-questions/how-to-change-or-recover-joomla-administrator-password.html)

This will work for Joomla 1.0.x . If you have ver. 1.5.x, it gets a little more complicated.

If you have access to a 1.5 install, you can generate your own password using this bit of code:

```
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword("yourpassword", $salt);
$password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

Note: The method that Deepali suggested will not work, because newest Joomla versions (1.5.x) are using the MD5 salted form, which means, that the password is saved in the database in the form of

> SaltedMD5:Salt

, so it would be harder to break for multiple accounts, as the salt is changed every time to a random string.

Comment: before raising the question i had done this but the password is stored in MD5 salt form  so what to do

Comment: In case you need to generate a new password, try using Phil Taylor's hash generator: http://blog.phil-taylor.com/2008/08/18/joomla-15x-password-hash-generator/  which can also be used to generate new passwords for users.

Answer (score 0):

just go through http://md5.gromweb.com/
create new password from here and put into your db  jos_users table